# Run Java command with classpath and library path from Golang

Tags: java, go, exec

For testing purposes, I have a helper object that starts an instance of AWS DynamoDB local in code. The structure of the Java code looks like this:

```
dynamodbtestutil\
- dynamodb_local_latest\
- - DynamoDBLocal.jar
- - DynamoDBLocal_lib\
```

The main class is in `DynamoDBLocal.jar` and all the library classes are in `DynamoDBLocal_lib`.

The command is executed via the following Go code:

```
path, _ := os.Getwd()
classPath := fmt.Sprintf("%s\\dynamodb_local_latest", path)
libraryPathArg := fmt.Sprintf("\"-Djava.library.path=%s\\DynamoDBLocal_lb\"", classPath)
cmd := exec.Command("java", "-cp", fmt.Sprintf("\"%s\"", classPath), libraryPathArg, "-jar", "DynamoDBLocal.jar", "-port", strconv.FormatInt(port, 10), "-inMemory", "-sharedDb")
cmd.Path = "java"
```

However, I cannot get this to work as Java cannot find the library path. The output I get is as follows:

> Command: java "-Djava.library.path=****\pkg\dynamodbtestutil\dynamodb_local_latest\DynamoDBLocal_lb" -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -port 8000 -inMemory -sharedDb
>
> Output: Error: Could not find or load main class "-Djava.library.path=*****\pkg\dynamodbtestutil\dynamodb_local_latest\DynamoDBLocal_lb"

Note: The *'s are inserted in place of the actual path.

This is clearly an issue with how I'm formatting the command but I'm not sure how this is supposed to work because I'm not familiar enough with the JRE to figure out what these values are supposed to be.

Comment: Does Java require its arguments to be quoted like this: `"\"-Djava.library.path=%s\\DynamoDBLocal_lb\""`? I think those inner `\"`'s in `libraryPathArg` are breaking it. I am only commenting as I don't know Java and its interpreter enough.

Comment: That's a problem specific to Windows and that particular argument. I have tried it without the quotes and it does break.

Comment: @blami Actually, you are correct. If called from the shell the quotes are required but if called from code they cause errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out my issue here. There were two main problems:

1. By setting `cmd.Path` to "java", I was telling Go that I wanted the command to run locally rather than from the entry in PATH for Java. Therefore, I do not need a fully qualified path to the directory of the .jar file.
2. Even running locally, the code exists in the `dynamodbtestutil\` directory, so I needed to provide the `classpath` argument. However, the value of "dynamodb_local_latest" was sufficient.
3. The value for the `-jar` argument also needs to be prefixed with this path.
4. The value for the `-Djava.library.path` also needs to be prefixed with this path
5. The `-Djava.library.path` argument should not have been inside quotes.

The code now looks like this:

```
cmd := exec.Command("java", "-classpath", "dynamodb_local_latest", "-Djava.library.path=dynamodb_local_latest\\DynamoDBLocal_lb", "-jar", "dynamodb_local_latest\\DynamoDBLocal.jar",
    "-port", strconv.FormatInt(port, 10), "-inMemory", "-sharedDb")
cmd.Path = "java"
```